# Manupulate main activity elements from non-activity java class

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I want to manupulate main activity elements such as TextView or Radiobutton from another java class. Also get information about text like getText() function.
How can I do this ?

```
public class main_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button query;

BusTimer bus_timer = new BusTimer();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

query=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b_sorgu);


query.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                bus_timer.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            }


        });

}
```

---

```
public class BusTimer extends Activity{

TextView cMeter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


cMeter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cMetre);

cMeter.setText("Hi");

}
```

I tried like this but it didnt work. Any help ?

Comment: **From another java class**. Is that another activity class??. Start with a basic tutorial for android

Comment: So what we call this ? I am new in android

Comment: i would suggest you go through some android tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be extending Activity unless it is really an activity not just a POJO.
What you need to do is pass the activity as a parameter to the other class and use that for the findViewById:

```
BusTimer bus_timer = new BusTimer(this);



public class BusTimer {


  TextView cMeter;

  public BusTimer(Activity activity){

  cMeter = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.cMetre);

  cMeter.setText("Hi");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 method to access elements and function from different class

1. using static elements
2. using a constructor